# Ubercart 3.x catalog page (terms categories) theme?

Tags: views, ubercart

How to change output theme for categories page in Ubercart 3 for Drupal 7?

Comment: What is categories page? could you please share an example link for the page?

Comment: It's page where shows catalog categires, table with div class "view-uc-catalog-terms"

Comment: I only need a link like example: /admin/store/orders/view

Comment: cats - http://3.reshleon.z8.ru/catalog subcats - http://3.reshleon.z8.ru/catalog/avtotovary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I not sure if you are referring to a taxonomy term page. In case if you are then please follow below mentioned steps:

1. Go to: admin/structure/views
2. Find a view called: Taxonomy term
3. Edit this view and add the fields as you wish
4. Under 'FORMAT' change to table, etc will change the overview of the taxonomy term page.

By modifying this view you will be able to change the layout, and the add more fields to the page.

Note: changing this view will change all the taxonomy term pages.